# Array Sorting in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have multiple arrays in in this format:

```
array = array(
    [0] => String
    [1] => String
    [2] => 1234
)
```

All of these arrays are contained in a single array. Is there any way i could sort each array in the Main array by the Number [2] from Highest to lowest. I have seen things like `rsort()`, but never got them to work. Thanks.

I just tried this, but it does not work for the last array?

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a[1] - $b[1];
}

$array = array(array("sdfdf", "dddfg", 153), array("dd", "dd", 80), array("dd", "ddd", 155));

usort($array, 'sortByOrder');
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/array_reverse

Comment: U need a[2] as highest and a[0] as lowest. Looks like u have issues with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php. Can u explain what is the problem ?

Comment: Sorting Multi-Dimensionnal array  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2

Comment: @Tectrendz What do you mean? I just need the array with the highest Int to go to the top

Comment: @bleuscyther This looks like what i need. Could you post an answer with some code. Also, he is using Keys with text, and i am using numbers. How would i do it my way?

Answer (score 1):

After further research i figured out that i could use this:

```
$array = array(array("sdfdf", "dddfg", 153), array("dd", "dd", 80), array("dd", "ddd", 155));

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[2] - $b[2];
});

print_r(array_reverse($array));
```

Then reverse the order of that array.